# position_dodge by colour but not pch with geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
df = data.frame(names = c(rep('var1',time=6),rep('var2',time=6)),
                dat = rnorm(n=12,sd=1:3),
                type=c(rep(c('mod1','mod2','mod3'),time=2)),
                length=c('1','1','2','1','3','3'))
```

I want a different colour for each type and different symbols for each length, which can be done using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=names,y=dat,pch=length,colour=type)) +
          geom_point()
```

[image]

However, I would like them to be "dodged" by colour/type but not by pch/length, which is what happens if I do this

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=names,y=dat,pch=length,colour=type)) +
         geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.6))
```

[image]

I can't find a command that would allow me to specify that the position_dodge should only apply to the colour but not pch. Any tips?

Comment: just a note your `df` given only had `var1` no `var2`

Comment: @user1317221_G Apologies, I edited my `df` for plotting but forgot to add the edited code to the question. I have now corrected and `df` has `var1` and `var2`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=names,y=dat,group=type)) +
       geom_point(aes(colour=type,pch=length),position=position_dodge(width=0.6))
```

using your `df` gives:

[image]